# Could not find an installable distribution at '/home/customize.iso'

Tags: virt-install

Below command work well for standard iso provided by Ubuntu but facing issue when customize iso is used.

virt-install --name=vm--vcpu=18 --ram=65536 --location=/home/customize.iso --network bridge=br0 --network bridge=br0 --disk path=/VMs/harddisk/vm.img -x "console=ttyS0" --nographics -v --debug

Debug log:

Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:54 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (cli:265) Launched with command line: /usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install --name=test --vcpu=18 --ram=65536 --location=/var/lib/libvirt/images/test-0_2_4.iso --network bridge=br0 --network bridge=br0 --disk path=/VMs/wdcsbm/wdcsbm.img -x console=ttyS0 --nographics -v --debug
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:54 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (cli:279) Requesting libvirt URI default
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:54 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (cli:282) Received libvirt URI qemu:///system
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:54 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (virt-install:358) Requesting virt method 'hvm', hv type 'default'.
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:54 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (virt-install:583) Received virt method 'kvm'
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:54 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (virt-install:584) Hypervisor name is 'hvm'
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:54 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (virt-install:270) Distilled --network options: ['bridge=br0', 'bridge=br0']
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:54 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (virt-install:316) --graphics compat generated: none
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:54 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (virt-install:183) Distilled --disk options: ['path=/VMs/test/test.img']
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (distroinstaller:283) installer.detect_distro returned=None
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (guest:251) Setting Guest.os_variant to 'None'
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] WARNING (virt-install:545) No operating system detected, VM performance may suffer. Specify an OS with --os-variant for optimal results.
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (virt-install:697) Guest.has_install_phase: True

Starting install...
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:56) Using scratchdir=/var/lib/libvirt/boot
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:503) Finding distro store for location=/var/lib/libvirt/images/test-0_2_4.iso
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:345) Running isoinfo: ['isoinfo', '-J', '-i', '/var/lib/libvirt/images/test-0_2_4.iso', '-x', '/.treeinfo']
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:89) Fetching URI: /.treeinfo
Retrieving file .treeinfo...                                                                                                                                               |    0 B  00:00:00
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:164) Saved file to /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinst-.treeinfo.d9lSWN
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:404) Did not find 'family' section in treeinfo
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:345) Running isoinfo: ['isoinfo', '-J', '-i', '/var/lib/libvirt/images/test-0_2_4.iso', '-x', '/content']
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:89) Fetching URI: /content
Retrieving file content...                                                                                                                                                 |    0 B  00:00:00
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:1144) No treearch found in uri, defaulting to arch=i386
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:357) Running isoinfo: ['isoinfo', '-J', '-i', '/var/lib/libvirt/images/test-0_2_4.iso', '-f']
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/current/images/MANIFEST) returning False
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/daily/MANIFEST) returning False
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/.disk/info) returning True
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:345) Running isoinfo: ['isoinfo', '-J', '-i', '/var/lib/libvirt/images/test-0_2_4.iso', '-x', '/.disk/info']
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:89) Fetching URI: /.disk/info
Retrieving file info...                                                                                                                                                    |   51 B  00:00:00
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:1191) Regex didn't match, not a Debian distro
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/Fedora) returning False
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/SL) returning False
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/CentOS) returning False
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/VERSION) returning False
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/.disk/info) returning True
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:345) Running isoinfo: ['isoinfo', '-J', '-i', '/var/lib/libvirt/images/test-0_2_4.iso', '-x', '/.disk/info']
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:89) Fetching URI: /.disk/info
Retrieving file info...                                                                                                                                                    |   51 B  00:00:00
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:1378) Regex didn't match, not a ALT Linux distro
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:1144) No treearch found in uri, defaulting to arch=i386
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/current/images/MANIFEST) returning False
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/daily/MANIFEST) returning False
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/.disk/info) returning True
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:345) Running isoinfo: ['isoinfo', '-J', '-i', '/var/lib/libvirt/images/test-0_2_4.iso', '-x', '/.disk/info']
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:89) Fetching URI: /.disk/info
Retrieving file info...                                                                                                                                                    |   51 B  00:00:00
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:1191) Regex didn't match, not a Ubuntu distro
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/Server) returning False
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/Client) returning False
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/RedHat) returning False
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/images/pxeboot/vmlinuz) returning False
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/ppc/ppc64/vmlinuz) returning False
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/images/boot.iso) returning False
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/boot/boot.iso) returning False
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/current/images/netboot/mini.iso) returning False
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/install/images/boot.iso) returning False
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/) returning False
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (cli:317)   File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 1008, in 
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 1002, in main
    start_install(guest, options)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 728, in start_install
    fail(e, do_exit=False)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/cli.py", line 317, in fail
    logging.debug("".join(traceback.format_stack()))

[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] ERROR (cli:318) Could not find an installable distribution at '/var/lib/libvirt/images/test-0_2_4.iso': The URL could not be accessed, maybe you mistyped?

The location must be the root directory of an install tree.
See virt-install man page for various distro examples.
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (cli:320)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 707, in start_install
    transient=options.transient)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 480, in start_install
    self._prepare_install(meter, dry)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 313, in _prepare_install
    self.installer.prepare(self, meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/installer.py", line 200, in prepare
    self._prepare(guest, meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/distroinstaller.py", line 220, in _prepare
    self._prepare_kernel_url(guest, fetcher)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/distroinstaller.py", line 127, in _prepare_kernel_url
    store = self._get_store(guest, fetcher)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/distroinstaller.py", line 114, in _get_store
    self._cached_store = urlfetcher.getDistroStore(guest, fetcher)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/urlfetcher.py", line 559, in getDistroStore
    (fetcher.location, extramsg)))
ValueError: Could not find an installable distribution at '/var/lib/libvirt/images/test-0_2_4.iso': The URL could not be accessed, maybe you mistyped?

The location must be the root directory of an install tree.
See virt-install man page for various distro examples.
[Thu, 07 Mar 2019 05:17:55 virt-install 17496] DEBUG (cli:331) Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start wdcsbm
otherwise, please restart your installation.
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start wdcsbm
otherwise, please restart your installation.
root@kvm01:/media/cdrom#

Any help from anyone will be appreciated.

Comment: The message in the title of this post is _not_ the error message you received. Read the actual error again.

Answer (score 1):

The manual says:

> you can pass the ISO to --location as well which works for some, but not all, CDROM media.

You can try (given a suitable `/mnt` dir)

```
mount /home/customize.iso /mnt
```

Then you replace `--location` as follows:

```
--location /mnt,kernel=/mnt/path/to/vmlinuz,initrd=/mnt/path/to/initrd.img
```

Adjust the paths based on your distribution kernel and initrd.

Answer (score 0):

You can try change --location to --cdrom which works for me and the full command be can be:

```
virt-install
--name=vm \
--vcpu=18 \
--ram=65536 \
--cdrom=/home/customize.iso \
--network bridge=br0 \
--network bridge=br0 \
--disk path=/VMs/harddisk/vm.img \
-x "console=ttyS0" --nographics \
-v --debug
```

And you can also refer to the manual for how virt-install use the options

```
       -c, --cdrom PATH
           ISO file or CDROM device to use for VM install media. After install, the the virtual CDROM device will remain attached to the VM, but with the ISO or
           host path media ejected.

       -l, --location OPTIONS
           Distribution tree installation source. virt-install can recognize certain distribution trees and fetches a bootable kernel/initrd pair to launch the
           install.

           --location allows things like --extra-args for kernel arguments, and using --initrd-inject. If you want to use those options with CDROM media, you can
           pass the ISO to --location as well which works for some, but not all, CDROM media.

           The "LOCATION" can take one of the following forms:

           https://host/path
               An HTTP server location containing an installable distribution image.

           ftp://host/path
               An FTP server location containing an installable distribution image.

           ISO Probe the ISO and extract files using 'isoinfo'
```